# How I can edit etc folder with sudo user

Tags: permissions, sudo

So I gave `sudo` privileges to a user and I turned off root login. Now I want to edit some server configs in `etc` folder, but I have no permission. I can't edit the config file to turn on login to root user. What I should do?

I am using Ubuntu 20. I added `sudo` to user by running `adduser user1` and `usermod -aG sudo user1` and made keys for that user to log in without password.

Then I disabled root login and authentication in `sshd_config` file and give permissions to `user1` with `sudo chown -R user1:user1 /home/user1` and `chmod 700/user1/.ssh` ,but when I try to edit server files with `user1` I have no permissions and if I give permissions to server files for `user1` I break root sudo and get in trouble. So `user1` never gets full privileges.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show **how** you tried to edit the file(s), and the exact error message

Answer (score 1):

Often on my local or when work on other computer(s) use SSH to login, then do my editing with nano.

```
GNU nano is a small and friendly text editor. It aims to emulate
the Pico text editor while also offering a few enhancements.
```

Believe is recommended for SSH to NOT enable root access from other machines, rather USERs login as themselves then use SUDO when required for root permission on other machines.

.